# Getting Unchecked or Unsafe Operations in Java

Tags: java

I have checked Other similar Questions.But not able to figure it out why its happening in my code:

```
// Array  of lists for Adjacency List Representation
LinkedList<Integer> adj[];

// Constructor
Prog1(int v) {
    V = v;
    array=new String[V];
    for(int i=0;i<V;i++)
        array[i]="*";

    adj = new LinkedList[v];
    for (int i=0; i<u; ++i) {
        adj[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }
}
```

Comment: The IDE usually tells you which line causes the problem and also gives you a suggestion how to fix it. The line ``adj[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>()`` will not work.

Comment: @f1sh Why won't it work?

Comment: @Nathan take a look at how ``adj`` is declared.

Comment: @f1sh Indeed w)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line causes the problem

```
adj = new LinkedList[v];
```

This compiles, but gives a warning, because it is of **raw type**, which basically means that it **isn't generic**. However,

```
adj = new LinkedList<>[v];
```

isn't valid in Java. You can't create an array of a generic type. Instead,create of `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adj;
```